# How place a function outside the return and then call it from onChange react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to put the function i have outside the return statement 
so I can call the function from "onChange" in my code and so I dont have to rewrite it again and again when i need it. I am new in JS and faced some difficulties trying. How can I fix this issue?

````
    {
      name: "Lombard",
      prevgroupinputrate: 0.01,
      currgroupinputrate: 0.02,
      mktratedelta: 0.03,
      mktrateestimate: 0.04
    },
    {
      name: "Other Secured",
      prevgroupinputrate: 0.01,
      currgroupinputrate: 0.02,
      mktratedelta: 0.033,
      mktrateestimate: 0.04
    },
    {
      name: "Unsecured",
      prevgroupinputrate: 0.01,
      currgroupinputrate: 0.02,
      mktratedelta: 0.0333,
      mktrateestimate: 0.04
    }
  ]);

return (
    <>
      {marketEstimateDataBCAssets.map((item, key) => (
          <input
            value={item.mktratedelta}
            onChange={e => {
              const newArr = marketEstimateDataBCAssets.map(el => {
                if (el.name === item.name) {
                  return {
                    ...el,
                    mktratedelta: parseFloat(e.target.value),
                    mktrateestimate: (
                      parseFloat(e.target.value) + item.currgroupinputrate
                    ).toFixed(4)
                  };
                }
                return el;
              });

              return setmarketEstimateData([...newArr]);
            }}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );```
````

Comment: Not sure what function you're talking about or where it's defined.

Comment: I mean the code starting from const

Comment: Do you know what a curried function is? You can use it like `const makeOnChange = (key,item)=>e=>your code` and then use it like `onChange=>{makeOnChanage(key,item)}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see, `onChange` prop takes a function, so you could set this function in a constant variable and pass it to `onChange` like this:

```js
const handleChange = (item) => e => {
    const newArr = marketEstimateDataBCAssets.map(el => {
        if (el.name === item.name) {
            return {
                ...el,
                mktratedelta: parseFloat(e.target.value),
                mktrateestimate: (
                    parseFloat(e.target.value) + item.currgroupinputrate
                ).toFixed(4)
            };
        }
        return el;
    });

    return setmarketEstimateData([...newArr]);
};

return (<>
        {marketEstimateDataBCAssets.map((item, key) => (
            <input
                key={key}
                value={item.mktratedelta}
                onChange={handleChange(item)}
            />
            < /div>
        ))}
    </>
)
```

Comment: Where does item and key in handleChange come from? you need to use a curried function here: `(item,key)=>e=>the function`

Comment: @HMR Correct, updated. I actually removed the key since it's not used inside

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function and just call that.

```
const myFunc = (e) => {
  const newArr = marketEstimateDataBCAssets.map(el => {
    if (el.name === item.name) {
      return {
        ...el,
        mktratedelta: parseFloat(e.target.value),
        mktrateestimate: (
          parseFloat(e.target.value) + item.currgroupinputrate
        ).toFixed(4)
      };
    }
    return el;
  });

  return setmarketEstimateData([...newArr]);
}
```

Then after that you can just call it like

```
<input value={item.mktratedelta} onChange={myFunc} />
```

OR

```
<input value={item.mktratedelta} onChange={this.myFunc} />
```

It depends where you define the function.

Comment: I would also pass `marketEstimateDataBCAssets` as an argument too. Then, to call the function:

<input value={item.mktratedelta} onChange={e => myFunc(e, marketEstimateDataBCAssets} />